# What is the easiest way to check the storage size of the full state DB?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

What is the easiest way to check the current size of the ethereum blockchain?

I'm thinking it would be:

```
cd <datadir>
du -sh chaindata
```

Just would like to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right using `du -hs ./ethereum/chaindata`  will gives you the synced blockchain size.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping there'd be an easier way to check this via some type of site like ethstats.net or etherscan.io - doesn't sound like it'd be too hard to implement for those guys and it would be cool to have a quick reference on the current synced chain size without needing a full node

Answer (score 1):

There's this site now by [Afri](https://keybase.io/5chdn) that gives you ***'current state size'*** and ***'full archive size'*** *(all states)*. It also has a pretty handy little [api](http://whataboutarchivenodes.5chdn.co/api.json) for pulling the data.

**Site: http://whataboutarchivenodes.5chdn.co/**

[image]